Wald Test Parameters used for Standard Error
I am doing a course covering General Linear Statistical Models, where we are studying models of the form $g(y)=Xβ$
We are learning about the Wald test which uses the asymptotic property of the MLE below to determine if a parameter is relevant or not

From what I understand, we plug in $\hat{\beta_1}$ for $\beta_1$ as it appears in the fisher information. My question is whether we do or don't plug in $\beta_1 = 0$ for this estimate of the standard deviation and why. (I believe R plugs in $\beta_1 = \hat{\beta_1}$, which is the source of this question)

Zach gave a nice answer below but I'm  not sure if it directly answers your question. You only need the t-test when testing for one coefficient and the wald test reduces to the t-test in that case. So, yes, when testing whether $\beta = 0$, there is an implicit minus zero in the numerator of $z^{*}$. I hope that helps.

@markleeds I thought the question is about the denominator.

@Zack Fisher Yes. you are correct. My mistake. But, in that case, I'm a little confused because one wants the standard deviation of $\hat{\beta}$ that comes from the corresponding element of covariance matrix which is $(X^{\prime} X)^{-1}$. Setting $\beta_{1} = 0$ would be using the value of $\beta_1$ under the null hypothesis which is giving too much strength to the null and would cause the t-statistic to go to $\infty$. In some hypothesis testing cases, it is sometimes okay to use the value under the null ( the z-test for proportions for example ) but not in this case.

@markleeds The OP didn't fully specify the variance model. In the common case where the variance model is free of $\beta$, we have parameter orthogonality between $\beta$ and $\sigma^2$, i.e., the information matrix is block diagonal. In that case, the value of $\beta_1$ only affects $\hat\sigma^2$ when computing something like the MSE. So setting $\beta_1=0$ only inflates the MSE, but it does not change the design matrix $X$, i.e., not dropping any columns from $X$. I believe it won't reduce the se to zero, but actually increases the se.

Hi Zach and Mark, thanks for the responses. My confusion was particularly related to whether we should plug in $\beta_1 = 0$ for the se, as this is what we assume under the null hypothesis. I'd be interested to know if this is undesirable somehow to giving too much weight to the null hypothesis and why that is a bad thing.
In our subject, we are purely using the asymptotic properties of the MLE, hence the fisher information.

Your choice would be similar to the first one in my answer (compared with the 3rd). It provides a valid asymptotic test, but hardly anything else. Such a se would be invalid if $H_0$  does not hold. As discussed above, this se is usually too big, if $H_0$ fails to hold. The 3rd and the 4th always provide consistent se estimates.

I'm sorry Malachy_P because I was using the covariance matrix from the regression and totally neglecting the fisher information. I don't know what the rules are for what to use when using the inverse Fisher Information to calculate the variance in a wald test.  Since they all go to the same thing in distribution it doesn't seem like it makes a heck of a difference ?  I'm more comfortable with the last one which is going to be closes to the t-test. In all the cases, $\theta_0$ is not used for the variance which is what I thought you were doing. So, my apologies for various careless-nesses.

Thanks to Zach for the detailed and useful  description of what converges and to what.

and also thanks for explanation of what's going on with the information matrix. I missed that comment earlier.  I'll have to look at a text in order to recall the details in detail but yours are helpful. Malachy_P: Basically, disregard whatever I said earlier. I was way off on this one from the beginning !!!!!!!!

Let $\mathcal{I}$ denote expected information and $I$ denote the observed information. Also let $\hat{\theta}$ denote the (unconstrained) MLE and $\tilde{\theta}$ denote the constrained MLE under $H_0$. $\beta$ would be a part of $\theta$ but $\theta$ usually also contains some additional scale parameters (commonly denoted as $\sigma$). Let $\theta_0$ be the true $\theta$ value.
Actually all the following four choices may give us an asymptotically valid test that is based on asymptotic normality of $\hat{\theta}$ under $H_0$:
$$
\mathcal{I}^{-1/2}\left(\tilde{\theta}\right)\left(\hat\theta-\theta_0\right)\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow N(0,Id)\\
{I}^{-1/2}\left(\tilde{\theta}\right)\left(\hat\theta-\theta_0\right)\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow N(0,Id)\\
\mathcal{I}^{-1/2}\left(\hat{\theta}\right)\left(\hat\theta-\theta_0\right)\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow N(0,Id)\\
{I}^{-1/2}\left(\hat{\theta}\right)\left(\hat\theta-\theta_0\right)\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow N(0,Id)\\
$$
In practice, the last two (especially the last one) are used more often than others. Typically, the last one is called "the" Wald test; but occasionally, some authors call the 3rd one the Wald test (as in your post).
(Your question would be similar to the first one, and they are identical if $\beta_1=\theta$ is the single unknown parameter, which is extremely rare since most models will allow for some scale parameter $\sigma>0$, which may or may not be functionally dependent on $\beta$.)
Benefits of the last two choices:

the model only needs to be fitted once (i.e., obtaining a single estimate $\hat\theta$ of $\theta$) and this saves computational effort, and
the se is consistent whether or not $H_0$ is true. This is beneficial because even if the test rejects $H_0$, the reported se is still a good approximation to the standard deviation of $\hat\beta$.

Among these two, Efron & Hinkley argued for the last one, since it is more data dependent compared to the  3rd one.
Disadvantages of the first two choices:
For the first two choices, we have to fit the model twice, under $H_0$ and under $H_0\cup H_1$ respectively. But then we can just rely on likelihood ratio test (LRT) directly, making the Wald-approximation to LRT unnecessary.
Also, the first two only provide valid se of $\hat\beta$ under $H_0$, which seems of little value, because if we believe $H_0$ is true, we'll just use $0$ as an estimate of $\beta_1$, rather than using $\hat\beta_1$.
To see that the se is inconsistent when $\beta_1\ne0$, take the true value of $\beta_1\rightarrow\infty$, the residual sum of square computed assuming $\beta_1=0$ would grow to $\infty$, making the se estimate growing to $\infty$.

PS1:
Actually, it is also possible to combine different information matrices and still get a valid test. In some models, a convex combination of expected and observed information leads to substantial computational simplicity.

PS2:
Yet another choice not discussed above is the score test, where we only need to fit the model under $H_0$. This is based on the asymptotic normality of efficient scores, rather than of $\hat\theta$. So it doesn't directly provide an estimate $\hat\theta$, but the test performance is usually fairly good and it is invariant to reparameterization, which is a big advantage compared to the Wald test.  In score test, $\mathcal{I}\left(\tilde\theta\right)$ is the most common and the safest choice.
